# Apache Cordova Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: cordova, gradle

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Failed to read key android-key from store "C:\dev\jd-release-key.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The Store PAssword and Key Password were interchanged so resolved the issue by swapping them